# python 2.7 name "x"not defined error after raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

My program should take user input of three integers and choose the highest valued odd number.

my code is:

```
X = int (raw_input ('Enter intenger: '))
y = int (raw_input ( 'Enter intenger: '))
z = int (raw_input ('Enter intenger: '))   
if x > y and x > z and x%2==1 :
    print 'x'
elif y > z and y%2==1:
    print 'y'
elif z >y and z%2==0 :
    print 'z'
else:
    print 'no odd numbers'
```

after being prompted to enter integers 3 times my error message is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

line 5, in

```
if x > y and x > z and x%2==1 :
```

NameError: name 'x' is not defined

I've tried writing:

```
x = x 

y = y

z = z
```

and bunch of other ideas as well and am not getting it.

thank you

Comment: Is it a typo, or do you actually have `X = int (raw_input ('Enter intenger: '))` as line 1?

Comment: capital X != lowercase x

Comment: Upvoters, care to explain?

Comment: Python is case sensitive X is not x

Comment: Update your post as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

`X = int (raw_input ('Enter intenger: '))` you have given `X` during varialbe declaration but you are using `x` while using

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is simply a typo:

change this:

```
X = int (raw_input ('Enter intenger: '))
```

to this:

```
x = int (raw_input ('Enter intenger: '))
```

Python variables are case sensitive so `X` is not the same thing as `x`

Comment: No problem happy to help! Happy coding